# Fix URL for Symfony2 UrlValidator

Tags: php, validation, symfony, url

Symfony2 URL Validator thinks that URL is invalid if there is no slash after domain prefix and before query string. For example:

- `http://www.example.com/?query=1`: valid URL
- `http://www.example.com?query=1`: invalid URL (missing slash after `.com` and before query=1)

Is there any way to fix this URL to pass validation?

Comment: `http://www.anyurl.com?query=1` IS an invalid url. If you want to change this behavior you have to create your own constraints.

Comment: Just do `str_replace("?","/?",$url)` after checking if a ? appears without / (but be aware that index.html?query is valid).

Comment: As @Leggendario said, you'll have less problem by using a valid URL instead of try to fix the validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extend symfony's UrlValidator from namespace Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints and fix a pattern to make your own URL constraint.

Now it's used

```
 const PATTERN = '~^
        (%s)://                                 # protocol
        (([\pL\pN-]+:)?([\pL\pN-]+)@)?          # basic auth
        (
            ([\pL\pN\pS-\.])+(\.?([\pL]|xn\-\-[\pL\pN-]+)+\.?) # a domain name
                |                                              # or
            \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}                 # a IP address
                |                                              # or
            \[
                (?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){6})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){5})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){4})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,1}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){3})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,2}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){2})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,3}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,4}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,5}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})):){0,6}(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})))?::))))
            \]  # a IPv6 address
        )
        (:[0-9]+)?                              # a port (optional)
        (/?|/\S+)                               # a /, nothing or a / with something
    $~ixu';
```

and you need

```
 (/?|\S+)                               # a /, nothing or something
```

(one slash removed from a pattern).

See also [How to Create a custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)